# Cannot see the Database in the object explorer of SS Management Studio as Server\Administrator

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Cannot see the Database in the object explorer of SS Management Studio (2008-R) as Server\Administrator. Should I Attach the database , I know where the path of datafile and logfile . I need to view the database schema of this database.

Comment: I tried to Attach this database but got this error:CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) while attempting to open or create the physical file ‘D:\SID_DNN\App_Data\Database.mdf’. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)  This is SS 2008-R2 version. I was “Attaching Database” as Server\Administrator. I need to view the data for reporting. This database this accessed by a live DNN module in our website. How do you suggest I view the schema and query the tables in this databases ? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The comment you added should be added into the question, not as comment.